# Find the residue of $ \bigl(\frac{z}{2z+1}\bigr)^3$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the residue of : $\displaystyle \left(\frac{z}{2z+1}\right)^3$

In this case we have $-\frac{1}{2}$ as a pole. Now I want to use the following formula:

$\displaystyle \frac{\phi^{k-1}(z_{0})}{(k-1)!}$

Now would I let $k = 3$ in this case then?

After that I am a little unsure what to do. The answer is $\displaystyle-\frac{3}{16}$ .

Comment: Figure out what $\phi$ is in your case.

Comment: My $\phi$ wouldnt be $z^3$ would it?

Comment: @DanielSmith: No.  You have extra factors of $2$ to account for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to not use that formula.  Note that $$\dfrac{z}{2z+1}=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{z}{z+\frac12}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{z+\frac{1}{2}}\right)=\frac12-\frac14\cdot\frac{1}{z+\frac12}.$$

You can use $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$ with $a=\dfrac12$ and $b=-\dfrac14\cdot\dfrac{1}{z+\frac12}$ to see that $\left(\dfrac{z}{2z+1}\right)^3 = -\dfrac{3}{16}\cdot\dfrac{1}{z+\frac12} + $ other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula you propose:

$$f(z)=\left[\frac z{2z+1}\right]^3=\frac18\left(1-\frac1{2z+1}\right)^3 \,,\,\text{ so} :$$

$$\lim_{z\to-\frac12}\;\frac1{2!}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\left[\left(z+\frac12\right)^3\frac{z^3}{(2z+1)^3}\right]=\lim_{z\to-\frac12}\;\frac1{16}6z=-\frac3{16}$$